# The words "Ion Drive" spoken by Scotty in TOS?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, episode-identification

I'm looking for a moment when I remember Scotty uttering the words - I think - "*Ion Drive*" while looking at a screen (or Kirk) in astonishment, or something in that vein.

I found these clips of dialogue on the bridge (near the end of this short video mostly about *Dr. Marc D. Rayman, Chief Propulsion Engineer, NASA JPL*, starting at about 01:55) from the episode Spock's Brain, but they don't seem to be sufficiently astonished, and they say "Ion Propulsion" rather than Ion Drive.

There is a distinction between the two terms in Memory Alpha that I don't understand.

But what I really need is a clip, or a GIF or some evidence of this moment.

Does it exist, or have I embellished upon it over the decades?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only other time Scotty uses the word "*Ion*" in any Trek episode (other than to refer to warp trails or ionic storms) is later in the [same episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spock's_Brain_(episode)). It would appear that in addition to using ion drives as propulsion, this species have also harnessed the **power of the ion** to power their civilisation. And yes, I'm aware that that's dumb.

> **SCOTT:** *Captain, that power we picked up above, we're getting closer.*
>
> **KIRK:** *A lot of it?*
>
> **SCOTT:** *Enough to push this planet out of orbit.*
>
> **KIRK:** *What source?*
>
> **SCOTT:** *Either a nuclear pile a hundred miles across or...*
>
> **KIRK:** *Or what?*
>
> **SCOTT:** *Ion power.*

Comment: Bingo! That's it exactly, great! "*Ion power*." This helps me try to locate some kind of visual representation, though it may not exist. If you could add a few more lines around that, or if the dialogue can be found on line somewhere, that would also be helpful to me. I have nothing here.

Comment: Well, they didn't say *which* ion. Maybe they are using triply charged excimeric Unobtanium ions. Valley of stability and all.

Comment: @uhoh - It's just treknobabble. Trying to make sense of nonsense is fun, but eventually you just have to refer to [Bellisario's maxim](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BellisariosMaxim); "*Don't examine this too closely."* - The story you're watching is being told by a small production team that has to work quickly, with limited budget and tight deadlines.

Comment: Half of me agrees, but there's still part of me sitting on the floor in front of the TV watching reruns after school in the 70's saying "Shhh! This is *not* silly!"

Comment: Makes me think of non-thermalized fusion reactors, which definitely are a step up.

Answer (score 6):

Ion Propulsion:

Menagerie, Part 1:

> COMPUTER: Library computer.
>   SPOCK: Lock on to sensors. Measure object now following the Enterprise.
>   COMPUTER: Computed. Object is a Class F shuttlecraft. Duranium metal shell, **ion engine power**
>   SPOCK: Stop. How long before shuttlecraft's fuel supply forces return to starbase?
>   COMPUTER: Computed. Shuttlecraft is already past point of safe return.

Spock's Brain:

> KIRK: What do you read, Mister Spock? 
>   SPOCK: Configuration unidentified. **Ion propulsion**, high velocity, though of a unique technology. 
>   KIRK: Any contact, Lieutenant? 
>   UHURA: Hailing on all frequencies, sir. All languages have been attempted. No response. Now using standard interstellar symbols. 
>   KIRK: Keep trying. 
>   UHURA: Aye, sir. 
>   KIRK: Magnification ten, Mister Chekov. 
>   CHEKOV: Aye, sir. Thirty eight thousand and closing. 
>   KIRK: Well, Scotty? 
>   SCOTT: It beats me, but isn't she a beauty?
>   KIRK: Interesting design.
>  
>   SCOTT: I've never seen anything like her. And **ion propulsion** at that. They could teach us a thing or two.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see any mention of *Menagerie, Part 1* when I searched Memory Alpha.

Comment: When searching for text, use google search ***terms*** **site:Chakoteya.net** ... chakoteya.net has full transcripts for trek series... and more.

Comment: Thank you for that also. I think I'll go read a few!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the Star Trek writers saw some of the very earliest mentions of ion propulsion in the technical news of the day. The first real working ion drive was 1959 at NASA Glenn with the first orbital test in 1970.  Maybe they saw the early research and just put it into Star Trek because it sounded technical and cool. Menagerie and Spock's Brain were 1966 and 1968 so it was a bit after the NASA Glenn experiments

Comment: Thanks, that's great to know! fyi I've just asked [When did ion propulsion first see some serious development efforts?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39848/12102) in Space Exploration SE.